# Interference of Geometry and counter of the page number

Tags: page-numbering, texmaker, geometry

I'm having troubles with the geometry package, it seems that every time that I reset the pagenumber to one, the geometry package treats it like it's the first page of the document. Now this is rather inconvenient since I use the geometry package to get a bindingoffset.

So each time I rest my pagenumber to 1, the bindingoffset gets set to the left (even if it isn't the first page, or any uneven page).

I also checked and it's not because of the titlepage-environment that the error occurs (notice that I also reset the page numbering for my bibliography).

**Warning, there is a bibliography in there, so be aware of that while compiling** (i left it in the document to show that it also does this error at the end).

> **supplementary (related) question**: Is there a way to reset the internal counter of the geometry package ? To force geometry to treat even numbered pages as right handed ones and uneven numbered pages as left handed ones starting from a given point in the tex-file ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\author{Some author}
\title{Some title}
\date{Some date}

\usepackage[twoside,bindingoffset=1cm,a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{The Section Manace}
\lipsum[5-10]
\section{Attack of the Sections}
\lipsum[11-17]
\section{Revenge of the Section}
\lipsum[18-24]
\section{A New Section}
\lipsum[25-30]
\section{The Section Strikes Back}
\lipsum[31-32]
\section{Return of the Section}
\lipsum[33-36]

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{LGT}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a default of a `twoside` document? That odd pages (including the first) get an appropriately-sided `bindingoffset`?

Comment: @Werner Yes (otherwise it would be a silly format indeed), but the problem is that whenever I reset my pagenumber to one, the geometry package treats it like it's an odd-numbered page (even if it might be even numbered).

Comment: Why might an odd-numbered page be even numbered"? Because you should issue a `\cleardoublepage` so you're always on the right side. Otherwise you'll be flip-flopping between odd/even on left/right, which isn't good.

Comment: @Werner, What I'm trying to do (in the enlisted document) is to make an article where I have a titlepage (1 page) and then start with the article. Now I have removed the numbering of the titlepage and resetted this to 1 when starting the article.

The problem is that it's going to be printed as a double-sided document and the bindingoffset got resetted after the resetting of the page numbering. So now it gives a binding offset in the wrong direction in the article itself.

Comment: @Nick If it's a double side document, odd numbers should be on right hand pages. Note that `geometry` has nothing to do with this. Note also that it's normal that the wider margin is the outer one.

Comment: @egreg, yes indeed and that makes sense. But (if the above code is compiled) the pagenumbers are the following: I-1-2-3-4-5-i, where I reset the page-number twice, now you see that the first two pages are both uneven, namely I and 1, but of course in my pdf-reader I is the uneven page, 1 is even and so on. This is NOT how geometry sees it and hence not how geometry treats it, i get even pages which become right hand pages.

Comment: @Nick: I my point of view it is rather the abstract within the `titlepage` environment which screws the whole pagenumbering up (well, dramatically spoken ;-)) It has nothing to do with `geometry`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I tested it, this was NOT the case. It also does the same thing when titlepage is not there and with the bibliography environment *removing the titlepage from the MMWE*.

Comment: @Nick Issue `\cleardoublepage` before `\pagenumbering`

Comment: @egreg, that would give me a blank page. That I can't have since I'm dealing with page-restrictions :(.

Comment: @Nick That's absurd; the right hand page must have an odd number.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I tried it again and it was indeed the titlepage-environment ! (if you put is as an answer you'll get accepted ;)).

Comment: @egreg, the issue was indeed what Christian Hupfer said (the titlepage environment), probably geometry doesn't count that one.

Comment: @Nick: I did not figure out why `titlepage` changes this, therefore no answer by me.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I see now. Why would an abstract within a titlepage mess up the geometry-numbering ?

Comment: @Nick: It is not the abstract, its the `titlepage` environment. I dropped the titlepage stuff of your document and the pagenumbering afterwards was correct (after omitting `\setcounter{page}{1}` of course)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, indeed ... But when I want to reset the numbering egreg's answer solved the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to ignore time honored conventions, according to which the right hand pages are odd numbered, just do the following:

```
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage % always clear the page before \pagenumbering
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{page}{0}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\the\numexpr\value{page}+1\relax}

\section{The Section Manace}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this nice answer. I will certainly use it if I want to ignore the time honored conventions ;). My problem was the fact that I used the titlepage-environment, apperantly geometry doesn't count titlepages which is why my bindingoffset was off with one page.

Comment: @Nick No, `geometry` has nothing to do with this. It just sets up the parameters that LaTeX uses for pagination. It's LaTeX that uses `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` respectively on pages where the `page` counter has an odd or even value respectively.

Comment: I indeed noticed when I started compiling, thanks for the answer it's real helpfull and completely solved my problem!